# add element before given javascript object in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some function that recieves javascript object "`element`" (there is no id speicified for it like `id=".."`). This js object is already created in DOM and is seen on the page.
For different reasons I am not able to change the object "element" before it comes to the function.

I need to add a new element `before` given object. I know that this can be done using jquery, but in this case I do not know how to convert javascript to jQuery (if this is possible).

Are there other options how to add element before given js element in DOM?

Comment: `$(element).before( $('<div />') )`

Comment: What does "convert javascript to jQuery" means? jQuery actually is a javascript framework...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the insertBefore method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore

Usage:

```
function myInsert(element, before) {
  before.parentNode.insertBefore(element,before);
}
```